# jQuery Sticky Header on Scroll un till the end of the Container

Tags: jquery, header, sticky

I want to stick a header when i scroll to that section of the page and it should stick to the top of the page until the container of that section ends.

Is there any good plugin to achieve this?

I tried the following but not able to get them to work

http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-stick-em
http://www.orangecoat.com/stickyscroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Harsha M V

Find the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dKDJz/4/) for your Question at http://jsfiddle.net/dKDJz/4/

```
var $sidebar = $("#sidebar"),
$window = $(window),
offset = $sidebar.offset(),
sbBottom = Math.abs($window.height() - (offset.top + $sidebar.height())),
prevScrollTop = 0;

$window.scroll(function() {

if (prevScrollTop < $window.scrollTop()) {
    $sidebar.removeClass('fixedTop');
    if ($window.scrollTop() > (sbBottom + 12)) {
        $sidebar.addClass('fixedBtm');
    } else {
        $sidebar.removeClass('fixedBtm');
    }
} else {

    $sidebar.removeClass('fixedBtm');
    if ($window.scrollTop() > sbBottom) {
        $sidebar.addClass('fixedTop');
    } else {
        $sidebar.removeClass('fixedTop');
    }
}


prevScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
});
```